# HTML and CSS fullscreen landing page

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if this fullscreen page with image and overlay is written clearly. I'm afraid that those two empty divs (topOverlay, and topImage) are not correct. Someone told me that I shouldn't use empty divs when there's another way to do it, but I couldn't find an alternative way in this case. Is there a different suitable tag for this instead of using `div`?

Everything works great otherwise. I just want it as clean as possible.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab);

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}


/* TOP - fullscreen image with overlay */
#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#topOverlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.98);
    z-index: 2;
}
#topImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../images/workspace.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 1;
}
#topTextWrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
#topText{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
#topText h1{
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#topTextDescription h2{
   font-size: 1.4em; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"> <!-- #top fullscreen image with site header -->
    <div id="topOverlay">
    </div>
    <div id="topTextWrapper">
        <div id="topText">
            <h1>Site header</h1>
            <div id="topTextDescription">
                <h2>Site description</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topImage">
    </div>
</div> <!-- END #top -->
```

Comment: Can I ask why do you have to use empty divs? What are you trying to achieve by using them? I don't fully understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is good, just try to use less ID and more classes with atomic classes, for example:

```
<div id="top" class="f100">
<div id="topOverlay"  class="f100 abs"></div>
<div id="topTextWrapper" class="f100 abs">
    <div id="topText">
        <h1 class="m0 p0">Site header</h1>
        <h2 class="m0 p0">Site description</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topImage"  class="f100"></div>
```

CSS :

```
    body, html{
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .m0{margin:0;}
    .p0{padding:0;}
    .f100{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
    .abs{position: absolute;}

    #topOverlay{
        background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.98);
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #topImage{
        background: url("../images/workspace.jpg") cover center center;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #topTextWrapper{
        z-index: 3;
    }
    #topText{
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    #topText h1{
        font-size: 3.2em;
    }
    #topText h2{
       font-size: 1.4em;
    }
```

See especially how these 4 classes are used in the above example:

```
.m0{margin:0;}
.p0{padding:0;}
.f100{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.abs{position: absolute;}
```

I was able to reduce the CSS from 53 line to 35 ( 35% )
plus its more simple

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve the same effect with less markup, and limiting yourself to semantic markup.

Since the `#top` div just contains `<h1>` and `<h2>`, I think that a [`<header>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html#header) element would be appropriate, if you are using HTML5.

The background image and overlay are meant to cover the entire page, so why not just use the `<body>` element?  For the overlay, you can use the [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore).  Be sure to define `content: ""` and `display: block` on it.  I would use absolute positioning, setting all four edges to 0, to make the overlay cover the page.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab);

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/image_output/business-q-c-640-480-5.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
/* Cyan tint on the entire page */
body::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.98);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#top h1 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="top"> <!-- #top fullscreen image with site header -->
  <h1>Site header</h1>
  <h2>Site description</h2>
</header> <!-- END #top -->
```